# How to place img tag and div tag beside each other?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, tags, image

I'm trying to place a `div` beside my `img tag`, but the `div` is being displayed down the `img tag`, but i want it beside, how can we place `img and div tag` beside each other

```
 <img usemap="#ChartImageMap" src="@Url.Action("GetChart", "Home")" alt="Asp.Net Char" style="width:450px;height:300px;border-width:0px;" />
 <div id="map" style="height:300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Just use `display:inline` for your div tag. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qM5dZ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the div to display inline:

```
<div id="map" style="display:inline; height:300px;"></div>
```

You could also just use a span:

```
<span id="map" style="height:300px;"></span>
```

Comment: i want the div and img to be displayed beside each other i.e in the same row...after using the display:inline property, the map itself is not being displayed anywhere

Comment: Try setting the img to float left.